# UITextField iOS: how to deal with the dismiss keyboard button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uitextfield

On the iPhone in Landscape orientation, there is a button in the lower right corner that causes the keyboard to dismiss.  I really don't want this button to be there, since I have a Done button already and users should only be able to stop editing the textfield by pressing this Done button (which has to be there to address portrait orientation anyway).

I'm wondering if there's a way to remove that keyboard dismissal button, or if not, I'd appreciate any suggestions for UITextField delegate behavior that differentiates between proper dismissal (Done button pressed) and improper (first responder might resign even though Done button not pressed, e.g. because of aforementioned problem button or view controller dismissal).

Comment: How is dismissing the keyboard using the keyboard dismissal button considered "improper"? Just react to the proper delegate method either way. All your own "Done" button should do is resign the first responder. Then your delegate will be called either way.

Comment: Preventing your users from doing something they are used to being able to do is a surefire way to annoy them. Can you predict every user's habits so perfectly that you can assert that the dismiss button should really be removed?

Comment: I guess I thought this was a pretty reasonable question, but from the first two reactions I suspect I'm thinking about this wrong.  
What I was taking issue with is the redundancy in the two buttons (dismiss and done), because in my simple setup the user just puts text into a bunch of text fields and then hits a submit button to send the results off.  For this, dismissing the keyboard and hitting done have the same function: they resign the first responder and leave the text that user has written thus far in the field.

Comment: That's why I'm asking about differentiating between the two.  It seemed to me that I need to have a Done button both because it's an expected way to dismiss a keyboard and because there is no other default for portrait.  But now that I have a Done button I have redundancy and that seems no good either.

Comment: "Done" should mean just that, "I'm done, submit the data". Dismissing the keyboard doesn't mean that at all. So you do have two different functions for the two different buttons if you look at it that way. Or do you also have a "Submit" button? If so, what's the "Done" button for?

Comment: Ok hmm.. all i need the button for is dismissing the keyboard.  I could also call it "return" i suppose   But i figure i do need a return-type button of some kind to deal with portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is declare a variable, something like, `isDismissedProperly` and initiate it to `false`. Then subscribe to keyboard show and hide notifications. `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification`. In the target method for done button(as mentioned in the question), change the `isDismissedProperly` to true. And in the keyboardDidHide method, you can check if `isDismissedProperly` is true or false.

If it's true, then user dismissed the keyboard by pressing done button.

Hope it helps!